# Error : Unable to resolve dependencies in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am new in android studio. I just downloaded **`android studio 3.0.1`** version and made a new project in it.

I am getting "Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0." error and some more errors like these.

I have gone through similar answers on stack overflow but nothing seems to work for me. I have also disabled offline work still I am getting these errors.

These are the errors I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Are you importing existing project or creating new Project ?

Comment: Make sure you have unchecked offline work! Or else, Go to File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.